# error while compiling net beans web servicee project with maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, geoip

> I first describe what i tried. I have a web service created in net
>   beans. It works fine. and i want to use GeoIP in my project [link][1]
>   so the [tutorial][2] says me to install with maven. so i have
>   downloaded the [maven][3]. then i extracted whole folder and followed
>   the instruction to add environment variables and i have tested it by
>   running "`mvn -version`" in cmd. every thing seemed good up to here.
>   then i thought that i must add a xml file named "pom" to the root
>   directory of my project(web service) due to this [documenttions][4].
>   now it says i must run this : "`mvn build`". i tried that in cmd. but
>   it told me that the directory is incorrect. i changed the cmd's
>   directory to the root folder of the "web service" project. and the run
>   the mvn build. but i still have errors.

error message:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building geo-maven 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.116 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-13T12:48:00+04:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/90M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "build". You must specify a valid lifecycle phas
e or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-ar
tifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate,
initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resou
rces, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, gen
erate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes
, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-i
ntegration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site
, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhase
NotFoundException

now my mind is blowing.

please help me!


  [1]: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/
  [2]: http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-java/
  [3]: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
  [4]: http://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/
```

Answer (score -1):

You've got: *Unknown lifecycle phase "build"*.
Meaning the command you gave *mvn build* almost makes no sense.

You may have read the Maven documentation, e.g. [introduction-to-the-lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), and you'll learn about maven phases and goals to issue the right command.

For now, try the most common *mvn clean install*.

Comment: I can't get the point. I have tried clean install. I still can't understand maven's job. after this process done, can i use the geoIP's classes in my project? is there any way to use geoIP easier? i mean without using maven. just like a simple library to get data from mmdb files.

Comment: If your goal is just to avoid Maven, you could download the [GeoIP2 zip file with dependencies](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/releases).